# fopen PHP syntax error unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to `fopen()` a debugging text file, which I have simply named debug.txt and put it on my desktop.  I am using PHP.  My code is simply

```
‪$debug_file = fopen( "C:\\Users\\joe\\Desktop\\debug.txt", "w" );
```

I keep getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$debug_file' (T_VARIABLE) ` on line 755, which is the line of code above.

I have checked the code before this line for a missing semicolon, as that often is the source of a syntax error, but the previous code is fine.  If I comment out my one line of code, the PHP file no longer gives a syntax error.

I was thinking that there is something wrong with the way I write the string literal file path to open.  I have tried to make it ok by escaping the backslashes.  I'm using Windows 10.  But that hasn't fixed the problem.  For the life of me I can't figure out what the syntax error is.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: As requested, the previous lines of code are:

```
add_shortcode('hide-it', 'hide_it_func');
function hide_it_func(){
    return;
}
```

Comment: Actually show the line or two of code above; it could also be missing brackets of similar

Comment: What you have is: [LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) before your dollar sign; Just retype the entire line and you should be fine.

Comment: Show the previous code lines. You **ARE** missing something. line 755 is just the first place that the missing something became relevant.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is the line(s) above, you either didn't end it with a semicolon or there's an open bracket, or something along those lines.

Comment: Not sure why this is a -2. I've developed for PHP for 8 years now and that's always the first thing to check!

Comment: This is not a good answer because it is speculation, and at the time of writing, there was not enough information in the question for this answer. This may be better as a comment.

Comment: However, it was the correct answer, because this is the correct answer almost 95% of the time.

Comment: NO, the answer is not correct. It was a character on the same line causing the problem.